# ActiveRecord: limit length of text when getting records from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 5. My database is Postgres 9.4.  I have a following table:

```
Post
id
post_title
post_content
```

My query for getting post is:

```
Post.limit(5).all
```

But I want each returned post should return limit content of `post_content`. For example, first 400 characters. I can do this by code, but I think it will be better if I can do this under database. (best is using ActiveRecord). Do we have any solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Its best if you let the framework do the text processing. PG has a function called `left` (ex: `left('blah blah', 5)`) but I am not sure how to use it with Rails.

Comment: dont recall the exact syntax. Should be something like `Post.find_by_sql ("SELECT LEFT(posts.post_content, 400) AS post_content FROM posts LIMIT 5")`

Comment: @MisterCal is there any ways that I can get all the other columns (without post_content) because it has "shorten content" already) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function and a column alias in a `select` method:

```
Post.select(:id, :post_title, "left('post_content', 5) as post_content")
```